# SDL: Unknown type SDL_Window on Xcode

Tags: c++, sdl, osx-yosemite

I'm moving from LibGDX and Java (finally!) to C++ and SDL. However, after following many setup videos and posts, I always get the same error:

```
Unknown type name SDL_Window
Unknown type name SDL_GLContext
```

Help is appreciated.

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#ifdef __IPHONEOS__
#   include <SDL2/SDL_opengles.h>
#else
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>
#endif

int width = 800;
int height = 600;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if(!window)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error failed to create window!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    if(!context)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error failed to create a context\n!";
        return 2;
    }

    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;

    glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    while(running)
    {

        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {

            running = event.type != SDL_QUIT;
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }


    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);


    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);


    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

(This is just a test script to see if it worked)

SDL2 - MacOSX 10.10 Beta - Xcode 6 Beta

Comment: Are you including the header files? Linking against the right libraries?

Comment: I have added the code. In Build Phases, I added SDL2.framework and OpenGL.framework

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like you have downloaded the framework etc and put it in your build phase but possibly you have forgotten to alter the project settings for additional header and framework search paths.

If you want an easy start this tutorial has a link to an Xcode template to download from Github which will have the relevant project settings in.

- Tutorial - http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-in-xcode-osx/
- Direct link to template - https://github.com/Zammalad/SDL2-XCode-Template

Comment: I still get the Unknown type name SDL_Window and SDL_Renderer errors with your template. Could it be a problem with OS X 10.10?

Answer (score 0):

Check your build settings. The template mentioned (in the other answer) uses the following header search paths: `/usr/include /usr/local/include`

I added a third one: `/opt/local/include/SDL2`

Note, that this third one comes from MacPorts